# STM32 Virtual COM port baud rate

Tags: usb, stm32, stm32f4

I'm using the STM32 VCP firmware and I want to transmit data to my PC from STM32F4 discovery board.
The configuration of the virtual COM port is fine, the properties are the following in device manager:

[image: VCP configurations]

In english: 9600 bit/s, 8 data bit, no parity, 1 stop bit, no hardware flow control.
I'm trying to receive characters in Realterm with these parameters, but I don't get them, it looks like following:

[image: Realterm screenshot]

What could I do wrong?

**EDIT:**

The MCU sends with the following code snippet:

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
  uint8_t Buf[] = "test";
  HAL_Delay(1000);
  while (1)
  {
      CDC_Transmit_FS(Buf, 4);
      HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: What data are you sending from the MCU?  How have you configured the display of RealTerm?  It appears that the PC is receiving 0x00 repeatedly.

Comment: I edited my question. The RealTerm display configuration is in ASCII, turning it in hex format, it gives really 0x00.

Comment: Are you giving it some delay between the transmits?

Comment: Yes, there is some delay between the transtmits.

Comment: Can you show the enclosing code snippet?

Comment: BTW, the device manager's port properties are always overridden by the software opening the port.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good point, but it looks as though that's what he wanted as that is how RealTerm is set up.

Comment: No, no, no! Don't implement delay like that! Probably it is just optimized away.

Comment: I added the code snippet to the question.
Yes, I thought, there is a problem with setting up RealTerm.

Comment: The loops not just ugly, they probably don't even work.

Comment: Without the loops, the program goes into the HardFault handler, thats why I think they will not optimized out.

Comment: I think there is some HAL_Delay function bundled with STM32 drivers. Use it please...

Comment: Or perform the transmission only once

Comment: Thank you, I'm using now the HAL_Delay function. But unfortunately the effect is the same.

Comment: I tried it with only one transmition, still the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the library to look at, but different sources suggest, that the CDC stuff is very buggy. Can you post the  `CDC_Transmit_FS` code you are using on pastebin, to verify it?

Comment: Yes, here are the called functions:
http://pastebin.com/1vFzP3e3  
http://pastebin.com/3ErHAgRv  
http://pastebin.com/vDJXbQJz     
http://pastebin.com/vWaYfLQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `CDC_Transmit_FS` implementation is buggy (at least in the version I am looking at):

```
uint8_t CDC_Transmit_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint16_t Len)
{
  uint8_t result = USBD_OK;
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 8 */
  USBD_CDC_SetTxBuffer(hUsbDevice_0, UserTxBufferFS, Len);  
  result = USBD_CDC_TransmitPacket(hUsbDevice_0);
  /* USER CODE END 8 */
  return result;
}
```

As you can see the `Buff` parameter is never used in the function.
You might try modifying the function, by copying the `Buff` into `UserTxBufferFS` (using `memcpy` or whatever).

Comment: You were right, using `memcpy(UserTxBufferFS, Buf, sizeof(char) * Len);` before `USBD_CDC_SetTxBuffer(hUsbDevice_0, UserTxBufferFS, Len);`, the data is transmitted, and I can see it in RealTerm. :)

Comment: Wow, that is exceptionally buggy for vendor-supplied framework sample code. How did that possibly get through QC?

Comment: @RBerteig: I've seen plenty of vendor-supplied framework code that was sufficiently rotten that I doubt any bugs ever caused any trouble because the code was just plain unworkable.  The above function looks like it might have a shot of working if `Buf` happens to equal `UserTxBufferFS`.

Comment: That was probably how it got through. I wish vendors spent a little more effort on code quality and testing for sample code.

Comment: This question was asked a while ago, but I thought I'd add: In the latest patch of ST's libraries this has been fixed. I thought this was breaking my code but it turns out it's not a problem. The fix was as simple as replacing `UserTxBufferFS` with `Buf`, apparently.